# BigQuery Error Message "No matching signature for aggregate function SUM for argument types: STRUCT"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find the daily transaction count and last 180day transaction count for a user and I'm receiving an error when I try to sum and count.
In the query below, I'm receiving the error "No matching signature for aggregate function SUM for argument types: STRUCT...." when I've just created the field daily_transaction_count as a count of unique IDs.

```
With Daily_transactions as
(select user,
day,
count(distinct transaction_id) as daily_transaction_count
from transactions_table
group by user, day
)

select
distinct t.user,
t.day,
sum(d.daily_transaction_count) as Last_180_day_transaction_count
\-----sum(d.daily_transaction_count) over (partition by t.user, t.day)

from Daily_transactions t
left join
(select day, daily_transaction_count
from Daily_transactions) d
on d.user=t.user
and d.day >=date_sub(t.day, INTERVAL 179 day)
and d.day<=t.day
group by t.user, t.day
```

I've already tried:

- recasting the data types as sum(CAST(d.daily_transaction_count as INT64))
- partition by instead of grouping by

Comment: Could you please share the "daily_transactions" schema? It seems that daily_transaction_count is a STRUCT field

Answer (score 0):

As far as your question and query are telling, everything seems to be fine.

I think it will be like eating a cake to give you the answer after having the table but before that,

I remember having similar issues usually caused by incomplete understanding of basics. For instance, you refer to struct data types in here, but you haven't done anything for it, that makes me guess to think there is something related to it in the answer but you haven't considered it yet. Anyways, I would recommend you to go through this page very slowly so you can grasp these basic concepts and many other basic concepts.

Considering your query error and your shared query your final res should be close to this:

```
SELECT 
   t.var1,
   t.var2,
   t.var3,
   SUM(broken.var4) var4
FROM table as t, JOIN UNNEST(table.broken) as broken
```

In other words, you just need to unnest the struct column that you are going to sum.